# Is it needed to maintain multiple resources in the vulkantextureimport Qt example for the swap chain?

Tags: qt, vulkan

I am trying to integrate Vulkan with QML, and to do that I looked at one of the examples provided by Qt for rendering a texture as underlay in Vulkan.

In the example, a custom render pass along with a frame buffer, which is the destination render target for the render pass, vertex buffer, uniform buffer, descriptor set, and all the other relevant Vulkan boilerplate is created.

It's possible I made some wrong assumptions. So after all these things are created, the frame buffer attachment is given to a `QSGTexture` to act as a wrapper for the texture, so Qt can use it.

This happens in the sync function:

```cpp
void CustomTextureNode::sync()
{
   
    //some code for initialization of resources and checking whether the size of the window has changed up                 //here  
    if (needsNew) {
        delete texture();
        freeTexture();
        buildTexture(m_size);
        QSGTexture *wrapper = QNativeInterface::QSGVulkanTexture::fromNative(m_texture,//the VkImage 
                                                                               VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,
                                                                               m_window,
                                                                               m_size);
        setTexture(wrapper);
        Q_ASSERT(wrapper->nativeInterface<QNativeInterface::QSGVulkanTexture>()->nativeImage() == m_texture);
    }

    m_t = float(static_cast<CustomTextureItem *>(m_item)->t());
}
```

Now, this is well and good, but I am confused about one thing. The uniform buffer and descriptor set use dynamic offset, which as far as I'm aware means the equivalent of having multiple of them for the swap chain.

That's also cool, but there is only a single frame buffer for this texture and each frame where the `render()` function is called, the rendering happens only to that buffer. The `render()` function is connected to the `QQuickWindow`'s `beforeRendering()`.

```cpp
 connect(m_window, &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, this, &CustomTextureNode::render);
```

And here is the actual `render()` function:

```cpp
void CustomTextureNode::render()
{

    if (!m_initialized)
        return;

    VkResult err = VK_SUCCESS;

    uint currentFrameSlot = m_window->graphicsStateInfo().currentFrameSlot;
    VkDeviceSize ubufOffset = currentFrameSlot * m_allocPerUbuf;
    void *p = nullptr;
    err = m_devFuncs->vkMapMemory(m_dev, m_ubufMem, ubufOffset, m_allocPerUbuf, 0, &p);
    if (err != VK_SUCCESS || !p)
        qFatal("Failed to map uniform buffer memory: %d", err);
    float t = m_t;
    memcpy(p, &t, 4);
    m_devFuncs->vkUnmapMemory(m_dev, m_ubufMem);
    //qDebug()<<currentFrameSlot;
    VkClearValue clearColor = {{ {0, 0, 0, 1} }};

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo rpBeginInfo = {};
    rpBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
    rpBeginInfo.renderPass = m_renderPass;
    rpBeginInfo.framebuffer = m_textureFramebuffer;
    rpBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.width = m_size.width();
    rpBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.height = m_size.height();
    rpBeginInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
    rpBeginInfo.pClearValues = &clearColor;

    QSGRendererInterface *rif = m_window->rendererInterface();
    VkCommandBuffer cmdBuf = *reinterpret_cast<VkCommandBuffer *>(
                rif->getResource(m_window, QSGRendererInterface::CommandListResource));

    m_devFuncs->vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmdBuf, &rpBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

    m_devFuncs->vkCmdBindPipeline(cmdBuf, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, m_pipeline);

    VkDeviceSize vbufOffset = 0;
    m_devFuncs->vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(cmdBuf, 0, 1, &m_vbuf, &vbufOffset);

    uint32_t dynamicOffset = m_allocPerUbuf * currentFrameSlot;
    m_devFuncs->vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(cmdBuf, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, m_pipelineLayout, 0, 1,
                                        &m_ubufDescriptor, 1, &dynamicOffset);

    VkViewport vp = { 0, 0, float(m_size.width()), float(m_size.height()), 0.0f, 1.0f };
    m_devFuncs->vkCmdSetViewport(cmdBuf, 0, 1, &vp);
    VkRect2D scissor = { { 0, 0 }, { uint32_t(m_size.width()), uint32_t(m_size.height()) } };
    m_devFuncs->vkCmdSetScissor(cmdBuf, 0, 1, &scissor);

    m_devFuncs->vkCmdDraw(cmdBuf, 4, 1, 0, 0);
    m_devFuncs->vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmdBuf);

    // Memory barrier before the texture can be used as a source.
    // Since we are not using a sub-pass, we have to do this explicitly.

    VkImageMemoryBarrier imageTransitionBarrier = {};
    imageTransitionBarrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    imageTransitionBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    imageTransitionBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
    imageTransitionBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    imageTransitionBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    imageTransitionBarrier.image = m_texture;
    imageTransitionBarrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    imageTransitionBarrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = imageTransitionBarrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    m_devFuncs->vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmdBuf,
                                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
                                     0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr,
                                     1, &imageTransitionBarrier);
}
```

I'm not even sure how this frame buffer that's custom created is rendered onto the screen. I am assuming it's copied to the frame buffer in Qt's internal swap chain to be presented, but I may be completely wrong.

Anyway, since we have a single frame buffer for that texture, doesn't that completely defeat the purpose of these additional uniform buffers and descriptor sets? And if not, why?